# Logs don't show up under Google App Engine project console

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm struggling with this basic stuff for weeks already.
Can't make simple logs working in my Google App Engine (JAVA) app.

I started from [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/configure-logging-in-google-app-engine/). Looks pretty straight forward.

Inside my Endpoint class I've defined a `Logger` like this:

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(GowMainEndpoint.class.getName());
```

Then in one of my endpoint methods I tried to log event like:

```
log.info("test");
```

There is nothing showing up in logs. I have logging.properties file and appengine-web.xml configured just like in the mentioned tutorial.

EDIT: Weird thing: `log.warning("test");` is showing up logs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out:

in the `logging.properties` file I've changed

```
.level = WARNING
```

to

```
.level = INFO
```

The comment line says:

`# Set the default logging level for all loggers to INFO`

but now I got the feeling it should be more like:

`# Set the MINIMUM logging level for all loggers to INFO`